# How to form this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table1**

```
ID |Name1 | Name2 | Name3
1 |Zaheer | Sachin | Adam
2 |Daniel| Jessica| Kevin
```

**Table2**

```
ID| Style| Name| Surname
1 | Bowler| Zaheer | Khan
2 | Keeper | Adam | Gilchrist
3 | Batsman | Sachin | Tendulkar
4 | Actor | Kevin| Spacey
5 | Actress | Jesica | Alba
6 | Actor| Daniel| Craig
```

**Result**

```
Style|Surname|Style|Surname|Style|Surname
Bowler | Khan |Batsman | Tendulkar |Keeper  | Gilchrist
Actor  | Craig|Actress | Alba      |Actor   | Spacey
```

I tried it with union, join but i aint getting required result

Comment: How do you even came up with that result?

Comment: Few people down voted without understanding the question.. Super

Comment: It's because your question is unclear. You need to explain it clearly.

Comment: I had specified clearly, someone from the mod team edited my question and made it look awkward. I added one more eg please check

Comment: @pranav012 . . . I formatted the tables in it.  There was definitely no intention to change the meaning of anything.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Post was voted down three times :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        t1.ID,
        t2.Style,
        t2.Surname,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.ID)
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t2.Name IN(t1.Name1, t1.Name2, t1.Name3)
)
SELECT
    Style   = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Style END),
    Surname = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Surname END),
    Style   = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Style END),
    Surname = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Surname END),
    Style   = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Style END),
    Surname = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Surname END)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

---

If you want the order of the columns to be `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3`, you need to unpivot `Table1` first:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        t1.ID,
        t2.Style,
        t2.Surname,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.No)
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, x.No, x.Name
        FROM Table1
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES
            (1, Name1), (2, Name2), (3, Name3)
        ) x (No, Name)
    ) t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t2.Name = t1.Name
)
SELECT
    Style   = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Style END),
    Surname = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Surname END),
    Style   = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Style END),
    Surname = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Surname END),
    Style   = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Style END),
    Surname = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Surname END)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks Felix . Perfect solution... Is it possible if i dont have ID column?

Answer (score 0):

SORRY:  MISREAD THE QUESTION -- PLEASE IGNORE THIS ANSWER

```
      It looks like you can get your result from just Table2:
      select style, surname from table2
```

Comment: not your fault. Someone edited my question and made it look like that